# After downloading file, it is corrupted

Tags: php, file, zend-framework

I'm currently making a controller to download files from the server.
It all happens in the index action:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $schuurName = $this->_getParam('storageID');
    $fileName = $this->_getParam('fileName');
    $name = explode('.', $fileName)[0];
    $path = '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'schuren' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $schuurName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $mimeType = mime_content_type($fileName);
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name . ';');
        $resource = fopen($path, 'r');
        while (!feof($resource)) {
            $chunk = fread($resource, 4096);
            echo $chunk;
        }
        $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }
    else {
        echo 'file doesn\'t exist';
    }

}
```

So the downloading works right now, I'm testing it with an image of 725 bytes. The problem is.. The image is corrupted so it couldn't be seen/edited. What am I doing wrong in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: use `'rb'` in `fopen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use binary mode.  Use the 'rb' flag.

From the php Manual : If you do not specify the 'b' flag when working with binary files, you may experience strange problems with your data, including broken image files and strange  problems with \r\n characters.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Alright I fixed it. The problem was that I was debugging using echo which made the file get corrupted by random strings.